# When I open logcat in my android studio the app closes

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat

when I open my Android Studio, if I don't invalidate cache and restart the app, it closes suddenly.
When I access the logcat screen, android studio closes instantly. Has the same thing happened to anyone before?.

From already thank you very much

Restartar the pc.-
Reinstall android studio.-

Comment: Really guessing here, but is your computer maybe running out of RAM?

Comment: I don't think so, I have 16GB of ram, in addition to the visual studio IDE I only have browsers open.